# Confusion regarding time complexity in the HHL algorithm

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm

In the paper of HHL algorithm ([Quantum algorithm for linear systems of equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171)), the time complexity of simulating $e^{i A t}$ for a hermitian matrix A is $\tilde{O}\left(\log (N) s^{2} t_0\right)$. Let $T$ be the time required for the phase estimation subroutine. Then, the total-time of simulation should be $T \cdot \tilde{O}\left(\log (N) s^{2} t_0\right)$.

Why, then, is the time complexity $\tilde{O}\left(\log (N) s^{2} \kappa^{2} / \epsilon\right)$?

In the subsection of error and run-time, they said that the run-time is $\tilde{O}\left(\kappa \left(T_B + t_0 s^2 \log (N) \right) \right)$; why is it not $T \cdot \log (N) s^{2} t_0$ in the run-time, just $\log (N) s^{2} t_0$? Does that mean they just simulate $e^{i A t}$ one time?

Why does [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0471) needs T times simulation?

Comment: Does the subsection on run-time and error analysis in the paper clarify your question?

Comment: No, it does not. I read the paper Quantum support vector machine for big feature and big data classification which have T simulation. So it confuses me, and thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

It is incorrect to say that the time of simulation is $T O(\log N s^2t)$
(it's also better written as $O(T\log N s^2t)$).
Conceptually, the simulation time ends at $O(\log N s^2t)$. If you want to consider the phase estimation, that's another (more complex) unitary, which includes hamiltonian simulation. If you were to think this in terms of function composition,
let $U=g(H,t,initial\_state,)$ be the function that performs hamiltonian simulation, and $f(U, args*)$ be the phase estimation subroutine, which takes as input a unitary (and the input to create the unitary, which in this case are the input of $g$, an hypotetical function (which you can imagine written in a quantum programming language) that builds the unitary for hamiltonian simulation U.

The reason there is no time dependence in the runtime is because they implicitely set $t=1$ and perform a time-indepentent Hamiltonian simulation. The other paper performs a time dependent simulation.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I also have some quesions. Is the matrix $A$ simulated $T$ times in phase estimation? If it is, should the complexity of phase extimation is $ \tilde{O}\left(T \cdot\log (N) s^{2} t_0\right)$? And how can i see the  Hamiltonian simulation is time independence or not?

Comment: yes is simulated T times, where T=1/epsilon, and epsilon is the precision in the eigenvalues you want. Is often implicit in the context of usage if the hamiltonian simulation is time dependent or not. If t=1 is time independent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If  $T$ is $1/ \epsilon$,  the total run-time  is $\tilde{O}\left(\kappa \left(T_B +1/ \epsilon * t_0 s^2 \log (N)  \right) \right)$?

Comment: perhaps. you need to perform an error analysis in order to choose the precision in the phase estimation. it should be written in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because they use $e^{iAt/T}$ as U in the subroutine of QPE, here, $T = 2^t$, where t is the number of qubits in the clock register. So even if QPE needs an exponential number of execution of this, it doesn't result in an exponential runtime.

(The trick is, I guess, in their part of non-exact QPE and relabeling. Not very sure about that tho, but their analysis about the time complexity does hold)